# Kendo UI for Angular 2 Grid dataBound event

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to capture the dataBound event of the grid similar to the one we had in the jQuery version of Kendo UI.  I need to perform an action after the data is loaded in the grid.

There is a dataStateChange event, but this event does not fire during the initial load.

Currently, I am using a timeout function to delay the execution, but this is not a permanent and reliable solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think it will suffice to use Angulars built in tools for this.

First of all it is advisable to create a new component for the grid:

grid.component.html

```
<kendo-grid [data]="tableData" #myTable>
  <kendo-grid-column field="ListItem" title="List Item">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        {{ dataItem.title }}
      </ng-template>  
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

The [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook of Angular will fire after init:

grid.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: `./table.component.html`,
})
export class TableComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('myTable') myTable: ElementRef;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('loaded', this.myTable);
  }

  public tableData = [
    { title: 'Number 1', id: 'one'},
    { title: 'Number 2', id: 'two'},
  ];
}
```

[Here is a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-61zdzb)

If the content of the array changes we would want to choose `AfterContentChecked`, which runs after each time a class member has changed and `detectChanges` has been called, so to say, when the content re-rendered during the lifecycle of the component.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thanks.  I was hoping for more component oriented approach though.  An event fired by the component itself.  I just checked their latest release and there is no dataBound event yet.  Perhaps using Angular's ngAfterViewInit might be the best option.

Comment: Sadly kendo seems to have chosen more template-oriented approaches to their components, presumably due to the fact that kendo is in its essence just a jquery plugin. For full component-based support you would have to look towards angular material.

I am having the same issues: I chose kendo for the implementation of a project within our company but due to issues like this we are switching away from kendo towards angular material.

Comment: This solution works. Mods, please mark it as solution.

Comment: handling the data changi inside ngOnChanges is probably the best, as the input might change and ngAfterViewInit is called just once!

Comment: When an input changes, change detection will run again. No need to use `ngOnChanges` unless there is special stuff to do with `onPush`

Comment: hi @mchl18 you are correct, it only works once after first initialization , if the grid data changes from more parent inputs, it isnt called anymore

Comment: @marksmith542 yes, if the data is changing we would need something like `afterContentChecked`

Comment: Yeah I would be more than happy if this could be flagged as the correct answer.